# TeeChart 2014 Where is TQRChart for Quickreports 5 in XE6?

Tags: teechart, c++builder-xe6

Can anyone help with this?

I have installed QR5 for XE6 but don't see any references of TQRReport for XE6 Builder C++ on the Teechart website.

Answer (score 2):

We've just published the TeeChart Standard 2014 packages for QuickReport 5 in C++Builder XE6 [here](https://www.steema.com/download/vcl).